# Nuxt3 deployment with Cloudflare pages failed

Tags: nuxtjs3, cloudflare-pages

I have successfully compiled my nuxt3 project locally. But the deployment is not working with cloud flare page

```
00:14:35.140    Executing user command: npm run generate
00:14:35.613    
00:14:35.613    > generate
00:14:35.613    > nuxt generate
00:14:35.614    
00:14:35.725    Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-rc.3-27567768.c1f728e
00:14:38.919    ✔ Using ~/components/content for components in Markdown
00:14:43.437    ℹ Vite client warmed up in 3072ms
00:14:44.646    ℹ Client built in 4280ms
00:14:44.681    ℹ Building server...
00:14:47.053    ✔ Server built in 2373ms
00:14:47.249    ✔ Generated public dist
00:14:47.249    ℹ Initializing prerenderer
00:14:50.871    ℹ Prerendering 4 initial routes with crawler
00:14:50.891      ├─ / (20ms) 
00:14:50.894      ├─ /200 (3ms) 
00:14:50.897      ├─ /404 (3ms) 
00:14:50.958      ├─ /api/_content/cache (61ms) 
00:14:50.971    ✔ You can now deploy .output/public to any static hosting!
00:14:51.017    Finished
00:14:51.018    Note: No functions dir at /functions found. Skipping.
00:14:51.018    Validating asset output directory
00:14:51.018    Error: Output directory ".output/public" not found.
00:14:52.095    Failed: build output directory not found
```

[image]

This is failed with "Error: Output directory ".output/public" not found." but actually the directory is generated few lines before. Any clue to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you give us more details regarding your configuration?

Comment: I have added my build configuration. Do you require any other information?

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue, after testings, this is what i found.

The documentation says `Use the nuxi generate command to build your application.` (https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/deployment#static-hosting).

### Configure Node Version

First, i'll add an `.nvmrc` file at the root of the project, so that Cloudflare doesn't use its default 12.18.0 version on deploy.

The content of the file is :

```
16
```

**sources:**

- nuxt 3 prerequisites : https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation/#prerequisites
- Node version on Cloudflare Pages : https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/build-configuration/#language-support-and-tools

### Configure the Cloudflare Page

Then i'm adding the configuration in the cloudflare interface with following :

- Build command: `npx nuxi generate`
- Build output directory: `/.output/public`
- Root directory: `/`

### Going further

Actually, it shouldn't be a problem to deploy easily on CF Pages: the team has added a `cloudflare_pages` preset right into nitro, the server library behind nuxt 3. https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/cloudflare#cloudflare-pages

I wasn't able to make this preset work for now, i'll update my answer when this has changed :)

Answer (score 4):

I worked around the problem with:

Adding Nitro output config [[1]](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config#nitro) [[2]](https://nitro.unjs.io/config/#output) to `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    "nitro": {
        "output": {
            dir: 'output',
            serverDir: 'output/server',
            publicDir: 'output/public'
        }
    }
})
```

In Cloudflare Pages, setting build output directory to: `server/output/public`.

I think the issue is caused by the default deployment script at CloudFlare side, checking the existence of `.output`, but not being able to see "hidden" (starting with dot) folders.

```
17:27:08.682    Validating asset output directory
17:27:08.682    Error: Output directory ".output/public" not found.
```

Edit (2022-07-10) found [a cleaner way](https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/issues/32#issuecomment-1112116389):

- add `"target" : "static"` to `nuxt.config.ts`
- Use as CloudFlare Pages build command: `./node_modules/.bin/nuxt generate`
- Set CloudFlare Pages build output directory to `dist`

Comment: Can you plese provide your final setup? I'm not being able to do that on a nuxt 3.5 project

Answer (score 1):

Just tell Nitro to generate for Cloudflare Pages and it should work. Remember to add a `.nvmrc` containing `16` in the project root folder or Cloudflare will use way too old npm version.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't make the .nvmrc work on my end, I ended up setting NODE_VERSION as
18.14.2 as an environment variable in cloudflare